# Compare the elements of two arrays by Id and remove the elements from the one array that are not presented in the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays of objects like this:

```
var arr1 = [{Id: 1, Name: "Test1"}, {Id: 2, Name: "Test2"}, {Id: 3, Name: "Test3"}, {Id: 4, Name: "Test4"}]

var arr2 = [{Id: 1, Name: "Test1"}, {Id: 3, Name: "Test3"}]
```

I need to compare the elements of the two arrays by `Id` and remove the elements from `arr1` that are not presented in `arr2` ( does not have element with that `Id`). How can I do this ?

Comment: You are seeking the intersection of 2 javascript object arrays.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723412/how-do-i-find-the-intersection-of-an-array-of-arrays-that-contain-objects-using

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a function that accepts any number of arrays, and returns only the items that are present in all of them.

```
function compare() {
    let arr = [...arguments];
    return arr.shift().filter( y => 
        arr.every( x => x.some( j => j.Id === y.Id) )
    )
}
```

```js
var arr1 = [{Id: 1, Name: "Test1"}, {Id: 2, Name: "Test2"}, {Id: 3, Name: "Test3"}, {Id: 4, Name: "Test4"}];
var arr2 = [{Id: 1, Name: "Test1"}, {Id: 3, Name: "Test3"}, {Id: 30, Name: "Test3"}];
var arr3 = [{Id: 1, Name: "Test1"}, {Id: 6, Name: "Test3"}, {Id: 30, Name: "Test3"}];

var new_arr = compare(arr1, arr2, arr3);
console.log(new_arr);

function compare() {
 let arr = [...arguments]
 
 return arr.shift().filter( y => 
   arr.every( x => x.some( j => j.Id === y.Id) )
  )
}
```

Comment: Appreciate this answers the question but was wondering if there was a way to do this for multiple arrays, not just 2?

Comment: @Seano - edited the answer to work with any number of arrays

Answer (score 11):

```
var res = arr1.filter(function(o) {
    return arr2.some(function(o2) {
        return o.Id === o2.Id;
    })
});
```

*shim, shim, shim.*

Answer (score 3):

Making use of a hash (a Set) will give a performance gain:

```js
var arr1 = [{Id: 1, Name: "Test1"}, {Id: 2, Name: "Test2"}, 
            {Id: 3, Name: "Test3"}, {Id: 4, Name: "Test4"}];

var arr2 = [{Id: 1, Name: "Test1"}, {Id: 3, Name: "Test3"}];

arr1 = arr1.filter(function (el) {
    return this.has(el.Id);
}, new Set(arr2.map(el => el.Id)));

console.log(arr1);
```

A new [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is created that gets the `Id` values from `arr2`:

```
"1","3"
```

That Set is passed as [the `thisArg` to `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), so that within the `filter` callback it is available as `this`.