# How to filter elements in an array that are not in another array using map and foreach

Tags: javascript

I want to find the elements in an array that are not present in a second array, using only the `.map()` and `.forEach()` methods (without using `.filter()` or other methods)

What I tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="res"></p>
        <script>
            var result = document.getElementById("res");
            var arr = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4];
            var scor = [2,3];
            x = arr.map(function(item){
              return scor.forEach(function(item1){
              if(item1 != item)
                return item;
                })
            })
           result.innerHTML = x;
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The answer should be `[1,1,4]` but I am getting `[,,,,,,,]`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You **should** use `filter` or `for` loop instead of `forEach`. `var filteredArr  = arr.filter(function (item) {
        return scor.indexOf(item) === -1;
    });` The problem is that, you cannot return something from `forEach` and `map` is used to modify every element of array, not filtering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare the elements of two arrays by Id and remove the elements from the one array that are not presented in the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983575/compare-the-elements-of-two-arrays-by-id-and-remove-the-elements-from-the-one-ar)

Comment: If the answer must be `[1,1,4]`, then why this restriction to only use `.map()` and `.forEach()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use map for this, it creates entry for every element, that's why you get bunch of `undefined`.

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would be more convenient here:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var scor = [2, 3];

var x = arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if (scor.indexOf(curr) === -1) {
    prev.push(curr);
  }
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: _no `filter` or Or other method._

Answer (score 1):

Your outer function (the one you pass to `.map`) returns nothing, so you end up with an array full of `undefined`s.

It's equivalent to

```
x = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4].map(function (item) {});
```

Comment: @Tushar ... not part of the original question.

Comment: :). Poor wording by OP :)