# How to leave repeated elements in two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

```
[
  {
    login: "LoginAAA",
    url: "someurl-aaa",
    number: 23
  },
  {
    login: "LoginBBB",
    url: "someurl-bbb",
    number: 56
  },
  {
    login: "LoginCCC",
    url: "someurl-ccc",
    number: 12
  },
    {
    login: "LoginDDD",
    url: "someurl-ddd",
    number: 45
  }
 ]
```

and

```
 [
  {
    login: "LoginAAA",
    url: "someurl-aaa",
    number: 23
  },
  {
    login: "LoginDDD",
    url: "someurl-ddd",
    number: 45
  },
    {
    login: "LoginZZZ",
    url: "someurl-zzz",
    number: 53
  }
 ]
```

Now, I need to compare arrays and filter those arrays and leave only repeated elements by one key e.g "login".

```
[
  {
    login: "LoginAAA",
    url: "someurl-aaa",
    number: 23
  },
  {
    login: "LoginDDD",
    url: "someurl-ddd",
    number: 45
  }
]
```

I think I have to use a filter() method but my tries don't bring the results. Should I run filter() for each array?

Comment: you will have to go through first array, and cache the logins on a separate cache object : var cache = {}; and when iterating through the second array you check if they exist in the cache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: This is not JSON and even if you get the data as JSON, the problem has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: You may use a .map function to go trought each element of each array

Comment: I think is a repeated question. See [Compare the elements of two arrays by Id and remove the elements from the one array that are not presented in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983575/compare-the-elements-of-two-arrays-by-id-and-remove-the-elements-from-the-one-ar)

Comment: Please post whatever code you have from your previous attempts.

Answer (score -1):

```
const array1 = []; // Your first array
const array2 = []; // Your second array
const logins2 = array2.map(login => {
    return login['login'];
});
duplicates = array1.filter(login => {
    return logins2.indexOf(login['login']) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: Those look like php methods, not javascript

Comment: After answering I found a better answer and have flagged as duplicate. Leaving this here in case it could be useful.