# How to perform union or intersection on an array of arrays with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of arrays:

```
var selected = [[1, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 5, 6], [1, 7]];
```

Underscore.js has convenient union and intersection methods but they work on passing each array individually as arguments.

How would I go about it if the number of arrays on which the set operations are to be performed is arbitrary?

[This question addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723412/how-do-i-find-the-intersection-of-an-array-of-arrays-that-contain-objects-using) something similar but it is for an array containing objects.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

One can use `apply` to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to a method.

For union:

```
// Outputs [1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7]
var selectedUnion = _.union.apply(_, selected);
```

For intersection:

```
// Outputs [1]
var selectedIntersection = _.intersection.apply(_, selected);
```

Comment: Any reason for passing in _ as the first argument? I understand that it sets 'this' in the function, but why not use 'null' or just 'this'. Can't say I totally understand 'this' in this context.

Comment: Good point. I don't think it affects anything in this use case. I think it was just an OCD to make the statement appear semantically better. :)

Comment: This is great, but how do we use this in a _.chain ?

Answer (score 5):

why not use *reduce* ?

```
_.reduce(selected,function(result,a){
    return _.intersection(result,a);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var centrifuge = _.spread(_.intersection);

alert(centrifuge([
  [1, 4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 5, 7],
  [1, 4, 5, 6],
  [1, 7]
]))


alert(centrifuge([
  [1, 4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7]
]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

var centrifuge = *.spread(*.intersection);

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could find: `_.union(...arrays)`.

This works in both Underscore.js and in Lodash.

The only major disadvantage I can think of is that it uses [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which won't work in Internet Explorer (unless you are using a tool like Babel to translate it).